# задача с счастливыми билетами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет, попалась задача на курсе по Python про счастливый билет. 
То есть программа должна проверять сумму первых трех цифр и последних трех цифр в числе. Я более менее сделал все, но! Если первой цифрой является 0, то последняя 4 становится 3. С другими  цифрами такого не происходит. Узнал это из того, что выводил каждую цифру числа на экран.

Вот мой код:

```
a = int(input())
a1 = int(a/100000)
a2 = int((float(a/100000) - a1)* 10)
a3 = int((float(a/10000) - int(a/10000))*10)
a4 = int((float(a/1000) - int(a/1000))*10)
a5 = int((float(a/100) - int(a/100))*10)
a6 = int((float(a/10) - int(a/10))*10)код 
if (a1 + a2 + a3) == (a4 + a5 + a6):
print('Счастливый')
else:
print('Обычный')
```

Вот код, как я узнал о проблеме:

```
a = int(input())
a1 = int(a/100000)
a2 = int((float(a/100000) - a1)* 10)
a3 = int((float(a/10000) - int(a/10000))*10)
a4 = int((float(a/1000) - int(a/1000))*10)
a5 = int((float(a/100) - int(a/100))*10)
a6 = int((float(a/10) - int(a/10))*10)
print(a1)
print(a2)
print(a3)
print(a4)
print(a5)
print(a6)
```

Comment: А нафига float?

Comment: Чего во что превращается? Входные данные-то где?

Comment: Используй целочисленное деление и остаток от деления.

Answer (score 9):

Зачем все эти сложности? Вы пишите на python'e, так используйте его функционал.

```
a = [int(i) for i in input()]
if sum(a[:3]) == sum(a[3:]):
    print('lucky ')
else:
    print('unlucky')
```

Либо, если вы хотите оперировать именно числами

```
a = int(input())  
sum_left = 0
sum_right = 0
for i in range(6):
    if i<3:
        sum_right += a // 10**i % 10
    else:
        sum_left  += a // 10**i % 10 
if sum_left == sum_right:
    print('lucky')
else:
    print('unlucky')
```

Кстати, если сравнить время работы этих двух методов, то выясниться, что 1-ый (который работает со строкой) почти в 1.3 раза быстрее 2-го (который работает с числами)

```
def solution1(s): 
    a = [int(i) for i in s]
    return sum(a[:3]) == sum(a[3:]) 

def solution2(s):  
    a = int(s)  
    sum_left = 0
    sum_right = 0 
    for i in range(6):
        if i<3:
            sum_right += a // 10**i % 10
        else:
            sum_left  += a // 10**i % 10  
    return sum_left == sum_right 

import random,string,time 

def random_string(ln=6):  
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(ln))

for N in range(3,10):
    print(' --- launch with data size 10^%s --- ' % N)
    sample = [random_string() for i in range(10**N)]

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in sample:
        solution1(i)
    time_of_sol1 = (time.time() - start_time)*1000
    print("solution #1: %s milliseconds" % time_of_sol1)

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in sample:
        solution2(i)
    time_of_sol2 = (time.time() - start_time)*1000
    print("solution #2: %s milliseconds" % time_of_sol2)

    if time_of_sol1<time_of_sol2:
        print('solution #1 is %s times faster than solution #2' % (time_of_sol2/time_of_sol1))
    else:
        print('solution #2 is %s times faster than solution #1' % (time_of_sol1/time_of_sol2))
    print('\n\n')
```

График зависимости времени от объема данных (по оси X степени 10), время в миллисекундах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходя из вышесказанного, советую пользоваться методом работы со строками.

Comment: Хотел сделать лучше, но че-то не получилось....

Comment: Ретурны лучше написать так: return sum_left == sum_right. У меня разница совсем не 1,3. Даже меньше 10%.

Comment: Как обернуть в функцию ваше решение (первый вариант решения, самый коротенький) ? Так чтоб у функции был параметр - это 6-значное число вводимое с клавиатуры. И чтоб эта функция потом вызывалась ниже.

Comment: вызов функции должен быть такой print(detect_lucky(int(input())))

Answer (score 0):

Не только 4 меняется на 3, но и 3 на 4. Неохота разбираться почему, наверняка из-за погрешностей двоичной арифметики.

Укорочу предыдущий ответ:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input()]
print(["unlucky","lucky"][sum(a[:3]) == sum(a[3:])])
```

Comment: Вы наверно хотели в конце `[-3:]`.

Comment: @MarianD в данном случае без разницы, числа шестизначные. В задаче об этом, правда, не сказано :)