# Задача "Счастливый билет"

Tags: python

на Python про "счастливый билет" писали множество вопросов, на которые достойные программисты давали исчерпывающие ответы, но я не нашёл ответа как и вопроса, про то как написать программу с использованием **"while"**, нужны ли для решения этой задачи циклы? если да, то как написать код используя цикл? будьте добры укажите путь истины.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106756/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82

Comment: Указанный "дубликат" на самом деле дубликатом не является, хотя и название совпадает - в задаче по ссылке из той темы "счастливость" совсем другая, чем в общепринятом смысле.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен именно `while`:

```
ticket = list(map(int, input()))
i = 0
while i<len(ticket):
    if sum(ticket[:i]) == sum(ticket[i:]):
        print('Yes')
        break
    i += 1
else:
    print('No')
```